# Flask - apache2 wsgi app with infinite loop thread

Tags: python, flask, apache2, mod-wsgi

I have a small flask app that runs on apache2 mod_wsgi, the app has a web interface and a separate thred that should run h24 on the server.
The problem is that while I'm connected to the web interface and the web server is serving the page the loop runs flawlessly, if I close the browser the task stops because apache stops the task inside the Flask app, when I browse it again it restarts back up.
Is there an apache2 setting or a code workaround to solve this?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName 192.168.123.108
WSGIDaemonProcess app user=pi group=pi threads=5 display-name=%{GROUP} home=/var/www/fbot
WSGIScriptAlias /fbot /var/www/fbot/app.wsgi
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

<Directory /var/www/fbot/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    WSGIProcessGroup app
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

```
app = Flask(__name__)
e = Engine(testing=True)

class Engine(Thread):

def __init__(self, testing):
    self.exch = Ex(testing=testing)
    thread = Thread(target=self.run, args=(testing, ))
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()


def run(self, testing):
    # loop 
    while True:
        #do things
        time.sleep(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to modify my virtual host configuration under apache:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess app ... inactivity-timeout=0 ....
```

This way if inactive it automatically restart the thread, the result is a continuous loop. It's running now at the moment I don't see memory issues